# empty() doesn't remove html content when checking source

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an AJAX call which returns some data from a PHP file. I am trying to empty some HTML content and replace it with the data returned from the PHP file. I'm using this to empty the content:

```
$('#due-tasks-content').empty();
```

and this to add the new content:

```
$('#due-tasks-content').html(data.due_tasks);
```

This seems to work, visually, but if I check the source of the page using the View Source browser option, the content is not removed. If I refresh the source page, the content is erased.

My question is, how do I erase the content without having to refresh? I've tried remove(), replaceWith() and empty() but they all seem to only erase the content visually, but not on the backend.

Update:

The problem is the following:

I have two table, A and B let's say.

Table A has a task, Table B is empty.

When the task is complete, it goes into Table B. At the end of the update function within the PHP file, PHP echo new updated tables which I get back in the Ajax call. I then need to remove the old tables with the new ones.

This works fine. With these table, I have some bootstrap modals which will appear when the user clicks the name column of the table, which will show the user some info. The modal is by ID.

When the task goes from Table A to Table B, when I click the name column on Table B, the modal doesn't show up and I'm not sure why. I now realized that I made a mistake by looking at the source as I understand that, that only shows how the page was loaded initially.

Comment: if you want to remove tasks or whatever from your back end you will need to use ajax to hit a web service you write that knows how to delete the tasks from whatever store (database) you are using.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: [What is the DOM?](https://css-tricks.com/dom/) That will answer your question.

Comment: View Source will not show you what the DOM is doing.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/mattwoodard/1ca86jfd/

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, jQuery's `html()` calls `empty()` internally, so you don't need to.

Secondly, the source is never changed, it is ....... wait for it ........ the source code.

When you add or remove something in the DOM with javascript, the source is not changed, the DOM is, and you can inspect the DOM by opening the console (F12).

Clicking "view source" does not show you the DOM, it shows you the content of the file you wanted to see the source of.

jQuery, and javascript, runs on the clientside, removing something in the DOM in the browser does not remove it on the serverside, that would require actual serverside code, which again could be called from the clientside with things like ajax.

Answer (score 0):

When you view the source in your browser, you view the document source that was loaded initially before any javascript has executed, not the actual DOM.

If you want to see the actual DOM, in Firefox you can select a section with your mouse and do a `view selection source`. That will show you the current selected section of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a full code example?  What it sounds to me is you are looking at the actual source as it is received to the client which will not change. The jQuery code manipulates the DOM but can not change what you originally received.